# Translate git-log old commiter timestamp to strict ISO 8601 timestamp

Tags: bash, git, sed

I am responsible for deploying an application and as part of the deployment process, I need to get the latest committer timestamp in strict ISO 8601 format and place it in the database. For recent versions of git, it's fairly straight forward:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:'%cI' -n1
2019-05-29T10:24:58+04:00
```

But unfortunately, I have a few older instances where the switch `%cI` does not exist in the installed git. So to get close to the ISO 8601, I use `%ci` instead, resulting in:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:%ci -n1
2019-05-29 10:24:58 +0400
```

We will eventually upgrade the machines to a later version of operating system, and consequently a more modern version of git. Newer versions of git has this in the man page:

```
   •   %ci: committer date, ISO 8601-like format

   •   %cI: committer date, strict ISO 8601 format
```

But in the meantime, I want to massage this ISO 8601-like string on the older machines to the strict ISO 8601 format above. I wrote a bad looking one-liner to do this and it seems to work:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:'%ci' -n1 | sed -e 's/ /T/1' -e 's/ //1' -e 's/.\{22\}/&:/1'
2019-05-29T10:24:58+04:00
```

Simply, it replaces the first space with a `T`, the second space with nothing and inserts a colon `:` at the 22nd character position. How do I do this better? I tried looking up ways to do this with the `date` command; no luck.

Answer (score 2):

you mean something like this?

```
date -d "$(git log --pretty=format:%ci -n1)" --iso-8601=seconds
```

Comment: `--iso-8601=seconds` is okay on my git-bash, but does not handle the timezone as expected on my `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS`. It still prints `+0800` instead of `+08:00`. `+'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z'` works for both.

Comment: @ElpieKay while this answer does get close to a solution, I need that colon which is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
$ echo '2019-05-29 10:24:58 +0400' | sed -e 's/ /T/' -e 's/ //' -e 's/..$/:\0/'
```

2019-05-29T10:24:58+04:00

Replace the first space with `T`, remove the second space, replace the last 2 characters with a colon and those 2 chars.